# Is it possible to change the datatype of a column from int to double without losing data with Laravel migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, alter-table, laravel-migrations

I'm trying to change the datatype one of my column. My migration to create table was:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('place_ratings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('places_id');
            $table->foreign('places_id')->references('id')->on('places');
            $table->integer('rating');
            $table->mediumText('comments');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I want to change the datatype of rating table from `integer` to `float`. I already have some data in my table and I don't want to lose them. So, how can I do that?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to export your data and check it in local database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to change that column using a simple migration, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#modifying-columns for additional info:

You need to install `composer require doctrine/dbal` first for the ability to generate sql that changes these columns.

```
Schema::table('place_ratings', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->decimal('rating', 16, 4)->change();
});
```

The `16` and `4` means the total length and the decimal precision, so in this case it would have numbers of range `0.0000` (nothing before the dot, 4 after) to `000000000000.0000` (12 before the dot, 4 after, so 16 total).

Be sure to run it locally first to make sure you don't have unwanted side effects.

Comment: I've some data in that column. And the type of rating column is now int. When I make the migration and change the data type to float, is there any possibility to lose those data in rating column?

Comment: Update: Worked. Thanks